# Why does Hibernate require a @GeneratedValue for cascading?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to persist an entity which both doesn't have a generated value for the identifier and also cascade persists another entity. However this combination doesn't seem to be possible. I'm using Spring Data JPA for saving the entities.

Let's say you have two entities, for e.g. Student and Address. For students you want to keep their registration date (let's assume it's always unique), name and address. From the address you want to only save the street for simplicity sake. When saving the Student entity you want to cascade persist the Address entity. So you create the following entities.

```
@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    private LocalDateTime registrationDateTime;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Address.class, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Address address;

    public Student(LocalDateTime registrationDateTime, String name, Address address) {
        setRegistrationDateTime(registrationDateTime);
        setName(name);
        setAddress(address);
    }

    public Student() {
    }

    // ...getters and setters omitted...

}
```

and:

```
@Entity
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String street;

    public Address(String street) {
        setStreet(street);
    }

    public Address() {
    }

    // ...getters and setters omitted...

}
```

When you execute the following code both entity are persisted but street is NULL.

```
Student student = new Student(LocalDateTime.now(), "John Doe");
student.setAddress(new Address("Mainstreet"));
studentRepository.save(student);
```

When I remove the @Id annotation from the LocalDateTime property and add the following code then the address is saved correctly.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
```

These are the queries which Hibernate executes (it seems odd by the way that it's inserting the student first since that entity needs the id of the address).

```
Hibernate: 

    alter table Student 
       drop constraint FKf12myy73nsf6soln9xli8th80
Hibernate: 

    drop table Address
Hibernate: 

    drop table Student
Hibernate: 

    drop sequence hibernate_sequence restrict
Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1
Hibernate: 

    create table Address (
       id integer not null,
        street varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    )
Hibernate: 

    create table Student (
       dateTime timestamp not null,
        name varchar(255) not null,
        address_id integer,
        primary key (dateTime)
    )
Hibernate: 

    alter table Student 
       add constraint FKf12myy73nsf6soln9xli8th80 
       foreign key (address_id) 
       references Address
Hibernate: 
    select
        student0_.dateTime as dateTime1_3_0_,
        student0_.address_id as address_3_3_0_,
        student0_.name as name2_3_0_ 
    from
        Student student0_ 
    where
        student0_.dateTime=?
Hibernate: 

values
    next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        Student
        (address_id, name, dateTime) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        Address
        (street, id) 
    values
        (?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    update
        Student 
    set
        address_id=?,
        name=? 
    where
        dateTime=?
```

Comment: Hibernates need this because they want to be sure that there will be a unique key for cascading values correctly. You cann use `AUTO` or a own class for generation of keys - doesn´tm atter but need to be there.

Comment: Street is null or address is null?

Comment: And using `LocalDateTime` for id barely can be considered as a good idea

Comment: Using a timestamp as id is problematic, but LocalDateTime isn't even a timestamp. http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2018/03/14/dont-use-localdatetime/

Comment: @LenglBoy, but if a value is not unique then saving the `Student` also fails so it wouldn't even be possible to cascade. Furthermore, using `LocalDateTime` was only an example and I'm aware of the limitations. But thanks for pointing this out. I should have taken `ZonedDateTime` instead to avoid confusion.